# Why this question was downvoted and closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

> Drivers for recent (64-bit) version of Windows must be signed before
>   they'll load. Which certificate issuers can supply a certificate
>   suitable for this?

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6689758/what-certificate-do-i-need-for-windows-driver-signing

What it misses to be "well written"?

Comment: Am I missing something? The question is open, and has a net positive score.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be downvoted OR closed. It used to be closed, but please check the pre-edit version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently that question is open and positively scored. But take a look at the question's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6689758/revisions). That question used to be

> ### Where to buy certificate for driver signing?
>
> What are possible choices, which ones are cheaper?

And that is simply off-topic. That caused it to be closed and more than likely explains at least some of the downvotes it received.

Comment: Why it's offtopic? You _have_ to buy certificate if you want to distribute your driver. Does this mean that questions about programming tools are offtopic as well?

Comment: @user160319 No, it means that shopping and recommendation questions are off topic. They have been for a long time and always will be.

Comment: It's not about recommendations, it's about available choices. Is this offtopic as well?

Comment: Yep. That's a no go. It doesn't answer a practical programming question. It at most will invite link-only answers. They are not considered to be good questions for SO. A fair question to have as a developer, but simply not for this site.

Comment: Ughm. Then, if I _do_ need to ask about available choices for some programming-related question, where I can do that?

Comment: As I commented on your other question, there might be another site which is better suited, but the name escapes me. I'll have a look and let you know.

Comment: @user160319 As you will have noticed by now, http://slant.co was the site I wanted to point you at. Perhaps have a look to see if it is suitable for you.